# How to retrieve the result of a select query in Sqlite java android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm looking to retrieve the result of my request in variables to be able to check if the authentication is correct. In simple sql it does this with a Resultset but I understood that in Sqlite you have to use a Cursor. But I can't get a result. Here are two examples of what I have already tried :

```java
    public boolean checkAuthentication(String login, String password){

        boolean check = false;

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("SELECT * from Visiteur WHERE vis_login = ? and vis_mdp = ?");
        statement.bindString(1, login);
        statement.bindString(2, password);
        //statement.execute();
        return check;

    }

    public boolean checkAuthentication2(String login, String password){

        boolean check = false;
        String log = null;
        String pass = null;

        String sql = "SELECT * from Visiteur WHERE vis_login = ? and vis_mdp = ?";
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.bindString(1, login);
        statement.bindString(2, password);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            log =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vis_login"));
            pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vis_mdp"));
            Log.d("WHILE", log);
        }
        cursor.close();
        statement.close();

        if(log != null && pass != null){
            check = true;
        }


        return check;

    }
```

Thanks for responses.

Comment: You still need a ResultSet to iterate through using .next().

Comment: But I cannot use ResulSet in Sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rawQuery()` method to get a `Cursor` on which you don't have to iterate.
Just check if 1 row is returned because this is what you want to know: if a user exists with the specific `login` and `password`:

```
public boolean checkAuthentication(String login, String password){
    boolean check = false;
    String sql = "SELECT * from Visiteur WHERE vis_login = ? and vis_mdp = ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {login, password});
    check = cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return check;
}
```

Comment: But if I needed to store the values ​​to reuse them I proceed as in my second example?

Comment: If you mean the values of login and password you already have them because you pass them to the method.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. If I wanted to make a 
```Select vis_name from visitor where vis_id = 3``` 
for example. If i wanted to get the name to display it ?

Comment: Then you need another cursor: `Cursor c = rawQuery("Select vis_name from visitor where vis_id = 3", null); String name = ""; if (c.moveToFirst()) name = c.getString(0);`